# How can i start at a line with a csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

```
import glob
import csv

with open('last30daysdisabled.csv') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

How would i go about turning this into a list?

Comment: what's your purpose now?  It doesn't make sense since you edited your original post

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate()` you can have the line number as below, by default the count `start` is starting from 0, you can force it starting from 1:

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(reader,start=1):
    if line_number > 3:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) you can skip the first two lines by consuming them:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader)
next(reader)

for line in reader:
    print(line)
```